# How to idiomatically define a method that returns &str in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, enums

I have an enum that looks like this:

```rust
enum Foo {
  Bar,
  Baz,
}
```

I want to make a method that returns a &str based on which variant is passed.
Basically the Rust equivalent of the following Python code:

```py
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        ...
```

My first guess at doing this would be something like:

```rust
impl Foo {
  fn to_str(self) -> &str {
    match self {
      Self::Bar => "Example str",
      Self::Baz => "Another example str",
    }
  }
}
```

But I think there must be a better way to do this...
Maybe using traits or something like that? I have never used those before and I would be lying if said that I understand them.
The most important requirement is that it automatically works with `println!()` like this (if that is even possible):

```rust
println!("Current state: {}", Foo::Bar);
```

Comment: You want to implement the [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait for that.

Comment: ... or `#[derive(Debug)]`. Then you can return `String` (not `&str`) with `format!("{:#?}",self)`.